# Application will enter background -> go to root view menu

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing an application which has about 8 views and use navigation controller to navigate through. The first view is a main menu.

What i want is (of each view) to pop to the main view if the user press the home button (App did enter background).

I know the AppDelegate methods `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

And i know the method `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` called from the navigation controller.

I have tried to use popToRootViewControllerAnimated in applicationDidEnterBackground. 
Like:

```
[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But this does not work.

Can you please let me know what is the best option for this job?

Comment: Does changing to `...ControllerAnimated:NO]` work?

Comment: @q0re what is your rootViewController

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i think you try `NSNotificationCenter` like this:

inside `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` put this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"popToRoot" object:nil];
```

and in your `rootViewController's` `viewDidLoad` (that always appears on app launch) add this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(popToRootViewControllerAnimated) name:@"popToRoot" object:nil];
```

Then create a method in your `rootViewController`:

```
- (void)popToRootViewControllerAnimated
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Whenever the application will start first time, `NSNotificationCenter` will initialize for name `popToRoot` and prepare a method `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` for this.

And when application will go to background, `NSNotificationCenter` will pass a massage `@"popToRoot"` to `rootViewController's popToRootViewControllerAnimated` method and `viewcontroller` will pop to `rootview`

Comment: Works great, but is there a way to pop to root view controller `invisible` ? I always see the pop back to main menu after relaunch.

Comment: make `animated:NO` in `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 2):

have you tries it like this :-

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

replace your navigationController name with navigationController here.

**Edit:-**

in AppDelegate.h file

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UINavigationController *navMain;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navMain;
```

in AppDelegate.m file

```
@synthesize navMain;

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navMain = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navMain;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
    [self.navMain popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

try edited anwser

Comment: I have created a navigationController in appDelegate but this does not work. And `self` does not have a navigation controller in the appDelegate.

Comment: show me your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions full method from AppDelegate.m

Comment: In didFinis.. i only create a splash view without using a navigationcontroller.

Comment: okay i'll show you how i'm doing this take a look at my edited answer it works fine m updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but i use storyboard and the appDelegate `self` have not a attribute `viewController`.

Answer (score 0):

First: you should check wether the rootviewcontroller is a navigationController. Because self.window.rootViewController.navigationController is often nil.
Why?
Because the navigationController of a navigationController is 'nil'. Mostly, I set my rootViewController to be a navigationController

Secondly: 
You shouldn't do animated stuff when your application is about to quit. You should do it not-animated

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO
```

Answer (score 0):

crate a propery for UINavigationController in your AppDelegate class. In applicationDidEnterBackground: method call the popToRootViewController method by using the UINavigationController Property. For Suppose your propery name is navigationController then

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes thats right, but i must init the property `navigationController` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. And i can not init it without having a viewcontroller (in AppDelegate).