# back to previous controller before application enters background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i am developing an ios application that needs the user to login in order to get in to the system, if the user logged in and go to one of the view controllers in the application, then press home button. Now if he choose to open the application again (the application will enter forground), the application must redirect the user to the view controller he was viewing before he press the home button. Moreover, any data the user enters must be there.

Any Idea about how can I implement this in Xcode ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: "Now if he choose to open the application again" meaning: A.  After app was closed completely and start again.  B.  The app was brought back from suspended state?

Comment: the application back from background (enter forground)

Comment: i found this, is it the same ? is it an answer to my question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734529/application-will-enter-background-go-to-root-view-menu?rq=1

Comment: @etab - How can u ask is it an answer to your question... **You have to judge it** ;-b

Comment: hhhh, i ment dose it the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Save the viewController before app goes to background in the function `applicationWillResignActive`. And when app comes to foreground go to that viewController. If you have navigation based app, then call in `applicationWillEnterForeground`

```
[navigationController popToViewController:yourViewController];
```

Comment: i am not using navigation based app

Comment: what to do in this case?

Comment: what are you using then to manage view hierarchy?, `modalViewController`

Comment: UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

FilesDetailsViewController *myTab = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"filesDetails"];
        
[self presentViewController:myTab animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: and yes sometimes i use modalViewController using segue