# React Native pop to rootviewcontroller when app jump to background

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using React Native for my app and the rootviewcontroller is the login screen. I want my app back to the login screen when the app goes into background.

I try to achieve this using objective-c in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ReactCustomViewController *customViewController = (ReactCustomViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation                                                            moduleName:@"board"
launchOptions:options];
   customViewController.view = rootView;
}
```

Is it possible to do something like popToRootViewController to achieve the same result? Cause I don't want to init the root view overtime when it goes to background. Thanks.

Comment: Please refer this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734529/application-will-enter-background-go-to-root-view-menu". This link may help you to find out best solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It reminds me the concept of the UINavigationController. Actually I did something wrong in React Native and cause the NavigationController unable to popToTheRootView. I think it will work after fixing the problem.