# iOS: Reinitialize the the app from top view controller if it is coming from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I want to reinitialize my app from top view controller problematically. I want my app reload the views from start.
I have tried this in `applicationWillEnterForeground` method:

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        ActivityController *destViewController = (ActivityController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ActivityView"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your app to be running in the background, you can set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `true` in your app's `Info.plist`

Answer (score 0):

applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillEnterForeground,

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"popToRoot" object:nil];
```

and in your rootViewController's viewDidLoad (that always appears on app launch) add this:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(popToRootViewControllerAnimated) name:@"popToRoot" object:nil];
```

Then create a method in your rootViewController:

```
- (void)popToRootViewControllerAnimated
{
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

You should use `[self.navigationController popToViewController:ActivityController animated:NO];` instead of `popToRoot`.

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734529/application-will-enter-background-go-to-root-view-menu) for more details.